# How to pass an older date in echo?

Tags: linux, unix, echo

I'm using the below script to echo a dynamic date to a file;

```
purgedate=$(date +"$%m/%d/%Y %r" --date='6 month ago')

echo "6 months ago was" \"$purgedate\" > myFile.txt
```

The output I get is:

```
6 months ago was "$12/05/2016 12:20:11 AM"
```

How do I echo without the "$" sign before the date?
I want the following output, without the "$" before the date.

```
6 months ago was "12/05/2016 12:20:11 AM"
```

Comment: purgedate=$(date +"%m/%d/%Y %r" --date='6 month ago')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're getting a dollar sign in your output because you've included a dollar sign in your date format.

```
purgedate=$(date +"$%m/%d/%Y %r" --date='6 month ago')
                   ^
```

Remove it, and it will no longer be there. :-)

I should point out that the date format you're using is obsolete and imprecise. For any new development, you should consider [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) which has existed since 1988 and is THE standard way of representing dates.

And it may even give you opportunities for shortening things, too; `'+%Y-%m-%d'` can be replaced with `'+%F'` in most environments.

Answer (score 0):

You accidentally add '$' in your string: "**$**%m/%d/%Y %r".

By removing it, it works:

```
purgedate=$(date +"%m/%d/%Y %r" --date='6 month ago')
echo "6 months ago was" \"$purgedate\" > myFile.txt
```